# Access Form Records not showing

Tags: ms-access

I have a Form with Employee first and last names. I have come up with a code that will open another form with that employees details

```
Private Sub cmdRecords_Click()

 Dim QUOTE As String
 QUOTE = Chr(34)
 Dim name As String
     name = Me.NameFirst & " " & Me.NameLast

 Dim lookUp As String
     lookUp = "[EmployeeName] = " & QUOTE & name & QUOTE

    DoCmd.OpenForm "PayrollPeriod", acNormal, , lookUp

End Sub
```

The code works great for all but the fist record. It will open the next form with no results. However, if I go to the last record on the main form and enter a new record using the same first and last name, the records for the employ show up

The employees name has been changed for privacy
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code is not even close to doing what you think it is doing.

You need to learn a lot to do this:

See this youtube channel [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYMOUCVo86jEeMMdaaq03jQ_t9nFV737s) which should be able to help you.

Comment: Could you be more helpful? Also, I have seen almost every one of those videos. The code like I said works fine. It just won't find the first record. If I duplicate the first record and put in in the end, it'll find it just fine

Comment: The employee name should only be stored in one table.

Comment: It kinda is stored in one table. You need to reread the code. "me" implies the form. ".caption" implies I'm working with a form object.... So I'm getting Names from a textbox to LOOKUP the name in the table. This database was set in in Lotus probably before I was even born. A coworker and I are tasked with bringing this database into Access exactly as is.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution. There was an inconsistency with the spelling of the name. Whoever entered the data for employees, spelled the persons last name differently in each of the two tables. I was spelling it right when duplicating it causing it to show up. Went to the Employees table and fixed the name. Now everything looks good